# Test syntax returning odd results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The following three tests process, but give misleading results, where the applications default locale is `:en`

```
  test "locale signed in wrong" do
    sign_in users(:end_consumer_email)
puts users(:end_consumer_email).idiom.label.downcase
    I18n.locale = users(:end_consumer_email).idiom.label.downcase
puts I18n.locale
    assert I18n.locale != 'en'
  end

  test "locale signed in correct" do
    sign_in users(:end_consumer_email)
puts users(:end_consumer_email).idiom.label.downcase.to_s
    I18n.locale = users(:end_consumer_email).idiom.label.downcase
puts I18n.locale
    assert I18n.locale == 'es'
  end

  test "locale not signed in" do
puts I18n.locale
    assert I18n.locale == 'en'
  end
```

The first case puts `es es` and returns true.  But this is a mirage.
As the second test returns the same `es es` puts, but complains that `Expected false to be truthy.`
The third test returns `en` but has the same complaint about false being truthy?

So something is incorrect, and very misleading, between the logging and the actual processing of the test.  Rails 6.1.3, gem `capybara` is installed in the test block, but minitest is also installed as a dependency.

What is incorrect in the syntax of these tests?

Comment: I would recommend that you use `assert_equal` instead of `assert` for a situation like this.  Then when a test fails you will be able to see what the expected value was compared to the actual value.  What is the output when you do something like `assert_equal 'en', I18n.locale`?

Comment: That was it.  In the third case `assert_equal(:en, I18n.locale)` with symbol expected, which the error message returned.  While `assert_not_equal(:en, I18n.locale)` is the reverse truthy statement.